# r - rmongodb batch insert error: Expected a list of mongo.bson class objects

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

**Situation**

I have a list of athletes `lst_ath`

```
lst_ath <- structure(list(`1` = structure(c("1125266", "ath_1"), .Names = c("id", 
"name")), `2` = structure(c("1125265", "ath_2"), .Names = c("id", 
"name")), `3` = structure(c("1125264", "ath_3"), .Names = c("id", 
"name")), `4` = structure(c("1125263", "ath_4"), .Names = c("id", 
"name")), `5` = structure(c("1125262", "ath_5"), .Names = c("id", 
"name")), `6` = structure(c("1125261", "ath_6"), .Names = c("id", 
"name")), `7` = structure(c("1125260", "ath_7"), .Names = c("id", 
"name")), `8` = structure(c("1125259", "ath_8"), .Names = c("id", 
"name")), `9` = structure(c("1125258", "ath_9"), .Names = c("id", 
"name")), `10` = structure(c("1125257", "ath_10", "(NZ)"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "country"))), .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

And a connection to a local mongodb called "athletes", with a collection called "athletes"

```
> library(rmongodb)
> mongo <- mongo.create()
> 
> #check connection
> mongo.is.connected(mongo)
[1] TRUE
> 
> #set the database
> db <- "athletes"
> mongo.get.database.collections(mongo, db)
[1] "athletes.athletes"
```

And a `mongo.bson` object `query` from the list `lst_ath`

```
query <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst_ath)
str(query)
Class 'mongo.bson'  atomic [1:1] 0
  ..- attr(*, "mongo.bson")=<externalptr> 
>
```

**Issue**

I'm trying to batch insert the `query` object using `mongo.insert.batch(mongo, db, query)`, but get an error:

```
> mongo.insert.batch(mongo, db, query)
Error in mongo.insert.batch(mongo, db, query) : 
  Expected a list of mongo.bson class objects
```

As I created `query` with `mongo.bson.from.list(lst_ath)`, and my `str(query)` shows `Class 'mongo.bson'  atomic [1:1] 0` I can't figure out the error.

What am I missing?

**Update**

As well as @NicE 's solution, I also need to define the collection that is being inserted into, not just the database, i.e:

```
> #set the database
> db <- "athletes.athletes"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are making an array when you call `mongo.bson.from.list` on you list of vectors. Since `mongo.insert.batch` needs `query` to be a list of 'mongo.bson' it gives you an error.

Try this:

```
#make a mongo bson for each element of lst_ath
query <- lapply(lst_ath,function(x){mongo.bson.from.list(as.list(x))})


#check that query is a list of mongo.bson objects
str(query)
#List of 10
# $ 1 :Class 'mongo.bson'  atomic [1:1] 0
#  .. ..- attr(*, "mongo.bson")=<externalptr> 
# $ 2 :Class 'mongo.bson'  atomic [1:1] 0
#  .. ..- attr(*, "mongo.bson")=<externalptr> 
# $ 3 :Class 'mongo.bson'  atomic [1:1] 0
#  .. ..- attr(*, "mongo.bson")=<externalptr> 


#insert them
mongo.insert.batch(mongo, db, query)
```

Comment: Implementing your method I have the same output for `str(query)` as you, but on insert I now get a different 'error': `> mongo.insert.batch(mongo, db, query)` `[1] FALSE` `Warning message:` `In mongo.insert.batch(mongo, db, query) :`

Comment: It turns out I also hadn't defined the collection, I had just used the database. I should have set `db <- "athletes.athletes"`.