# r - converting Date to POSIXct to insert into mongodb

Tags: r, rmongodb

**Situation**

I have a data frame of athletes

```
df_ath <- structure(list(athlete = c("ath_1", "ath_2", "ath_3", "ath_4", 
    "ath_5"), country = c("AU", "AU", "AU", "AU", "AU"), birthdate = structure(c(12731, 
    13056, 11964, 12678, 13086), class = "Date")), .Names = c("athlete", 
    "country", "birthdate"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

where the format of `birthdate` is `Date`

```
> str(df_ath)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ athlete  : chr  "ath_1" "ath_2" "ath_3" "ath_4" ...
 $ country  : chr  "AU" "AU" "AU" "AU" ...
 $ birthdate: Date, format: "2004-11-09" "2005-09-30" ...
```

It's my understanding that mongodb uses UTC date formats, so I'm converting the `birthdate` variable using `as.POSIXct`

```
df_ath$birthdate <- as.POSIXct(df_ath$birthdate, tz="GMT")
```

I am then turning this into a list in order to create a bson object to `batch.insert` into a mongodb database ([as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28611202/4002530))

```
library(rmongodb)
lst_ath <- Map(Filter, list(Negate(is.na)), split(df_ath, row(df_ath)))
query <- lapply(lst_ath, function(x){mongo.bson.from.list(as.list(x))})
```

Which gives (the first item):

```
> query
[[1]]
    athlete : 2      ath_1
    country : 2      AU
    birthdate : 9    446772224
```

**Issue**

I then check the `birthdate` value has been converted correctly

```
> format(as.POSIXct(446772224, origin="1970-01-01"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "1984-02-28"
```

But it's showing `1984-02-28`, and not the expected `2004-11-09`.

Why is there a difference between the UTC date generated in my `query` step, and the actual `birthdate` variable?

**Notes**

I've tried calling `as.POSIXct` on strings of `birthdate` [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279711/convert-date-to-posixct) but got the same outcome.

**Edit**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1]  LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rmongodb_1.8.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] jsonlite_0.9.10 plyr_1.8.1      Rcpp_0.11.2     tools_3.1.2
```

**Edit 2 - response to @nicola**

```
> as.numeric(df_ath$birthdate)
[1] 1099958400 1128038400 1033689600 1095379200 1130630400
> mongo.bson.from.df(df_ath)
[[1]]
    athlete : 2      ath_1
    country : 2      AU
    birthdate : 9    446772224

[[2]]
    athlete : 2      ath_2
    country : 2      AU
    birthdate : 9    -1537998848
```

Comment: @nicola - a typo - it should be `df_ath` - I copied the wrong line. I've updated the question

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get `1099958400000` which is the correct value for the first date (if expressed in milliseconds).

Comment: @nicola That's odd. I've just restarted my session, cleared the environment and ran just the code given here in the question and still get the same date values. I've added `sessionInfo()` now too.

Comment: I installed `rmongodb` right now. Maybe try to reinstall it Edit: i saw your edit and we have the same version. Unlikely this is the issue. By the way, I'm on a Linux system.

Comment: @nicola just removed and re-installed rmongodb - no change in my answers.

Comment: Are date values converted correctly? What you have if you try `as.numeric(df_ath$birthdate)`? What happens if you execute directly `mongo.bson.from.df(df_ath)` (which works for me)?

Comment: @nicola I've added a second edit to show you outcome of both commands.

Comment: Should be a bug. I guess you should mail to `maintainer("rmongodb")`.

Comment: I've sent the maintainer an email. I'll update this post as and when I get a resolution. Thanks for your comments @nicola .

Comment: Can anybody else reproduce this? I ended with 
`[[1]]
 athlete : 2   ath_1
 country : 2   AU
 birthdate : 9   1099958400000`